# Is there a stopwatch app available that shows the time on the sidebar?

Tags: 16.04

I am loving Ubuntu 16.04 and was wondering if there was an app that has a stopwatch in it. But I want it to show the timer on the side bar as time goes by.
For example, I am studying and want to stop after 30 minutes. GNOME clocks does the job but I have to keep checking every now and then. I was wondering if there was a way to display how much time has passed on the little bar on the left.
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe even better: the **Hamster Indicator** installs from the official 16.04 repositories (Enter `sudo apt install hamster-indicator` in a terminal in case you are using the unity desktop environment).

It allows you to take the time on different tasks and analyze them afterwards.
It does not show the elapsed time constantly in the panel (per default, see comment), but you can set a notification after 30 minutes. Constantly seeing the time passing, may be even a distraction to some people.

Cheers

Comment: Just found out, it can even show the elapsed time. You just need to enter the following command in the terminal: `gconftool-2 --set "/apps/hamster-indicator/show_label" --type bool "true"`

Answer (score 1):

There is a bash app I wrote that might be over kill: https://askubuntu.com/a/837115/307523

[image: Lock screen timer giphy]

It displays a count down timer on the *top bar* though not the *side bar* like you requested.

The default time coincidentally to your needs is 30 minutes but you can change that when calling the app.

The app repetitively calls itself so after say 30 minutes you can add another ten minutes.

As the count down approaches zero message bubbles appear and soft chime is heard at 15, 10, 5, 3, 2 and 1 minute remaining.

When the count down timer hits zero the normal lock screen and password prompt appears.

Because the app is written in bash it can quickly be tailored to your needs.

Comment: Looks like a great app! Can I make it so that it rings every 10 minutes? I'm studying Japanese and usually take 10' for Vocab, Kanji and custom vocabulary decks in Anki. For example, I want to study 30' a day, with 10' each for every different subject.

Comment: @Morgoth Thanks for the compliment. Yes you can make it ring every 10 minutes. Although this question should have been posted under the link not here. Search for the line that reads: `case $MINUTES in 1|2|3|5|10|15|30|45|60|120|480|960|1920)` and change it to: `case $MINUTES in 10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80|90|100|110|120|130)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a Pomodoro type app. A pomodoro app is made for study time and breaks. You set how long to study for, then it goes off, gives you an ammount of time that you also set, then starts again with the study countdown.

[Wikipdeia entry on Pomodoro Technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pomodoro-indicator
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a timer section in the alarm clock applet.
Download it from [here](http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/#download).
[image]

Alternatively, you can install it with the following command

> sudo apt-get install alarm-clock-applet

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use this and see how it turns out. A question: I like the theme of the bar colors in your app link.  http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/screenshots/notification.png Do you know if I can use this theme on ubuntu 16.04? Or is it another distro?

Comment: This seems to be a screenshot from Ubuntu 9.04 or 9.10. Back then, Ubuntu used Gnome 2 instead of Unity. You can install MATE desktop, which is made from Gnome 2 (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/install-mate-desktop-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and try out some of these themes https://www.maketecheasier.com/9-great-mate-themes-linux/.