# How can I restrict users of computers to 2 hours only?

Tags: user-management

I work in a library and I want to restrict users of computers to 2 hours only. Then lock them out and allow another user to use the computer. I am using Ubuntu and would like to know if there is a free software I could use to do this.

Comment: which desktop are you using on it?  some have a typing break timer that will log you out  after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Are all the library desktop computers using Ubuntu? If so, ***BRAVO!!!*** If not, however, what operating system are they running?

Comment: using Ubuntu 16, and am looking for a software I could deploy on the desktops and managed from the admin desktop all ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Bash script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu) will lock screen after an interval you specify and require the password to reactivate it.

It gives a count down notification bubble and soft sound at 2 hours, 1 hour, 45, 30, 15, 10, 5, 3, 2 and 1 minute remaining.

As I wrote the script I'd be happy to modify it for anyone. Because it's written in Bash millions of other people with beginner scripting skills can change it as well.