# Windows Subsystem for Linux desktop shortcut to GUI

Tags: bash, gui, shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, yad

I have a bash script called [lock-screen-timer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu/837115#837115) which calls `yad` to mount a GUI dialog box. Under Windows 10 and the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) I can run it from the bash prompt (note VcXsrv has to be installed first). I can't figure out how to create a working desktop shortcut in Windows 10. I can create the shortcut on the Windows 10 desktop OK...

[image: Lock Screen Timer Shortcut]

... it just doesn't run when I click on it. I've looked at many websites without any luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why didn't I think of that?

This is one of those solutions where you look at it and think "Why didn't I think of that?". Unfortunately I had to look at many websites with wrong suggestions or over-kill such as "how to use regedit to run shortcut as admin".

## Having the right parameters

Right click on your Windows 10 desktop and setup your shortcut to look like this:

[image: Windows 10 shortcut properties]

The full line for the `Target` field should look like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "cd && DISPLAY=:0 /mnt/e/bin/lock-screen-timer"
```

**NOTE:** Most users will use `/mnt/c/....` as their path but I'm dual-booting and the same script is shared by WSL and Ubuntu 16.04 so must be on a separate NTFS partition I've called `/mnt/e`. WSL cannot write to a Linux `ext4` drive and Linux nor Windows Apps can write to a WSL sub-directory. It's complicated...

Also note the `DISPLAY=:0` parameter accommodates calling a bash GUI script but the same is likely true if calling `gedit` or `nautilus` which are my next desktop shortcut projects. If not, I'll revise this answer..

Click the `Change Icon` button to get a default list of icons to choose from. This is where the clock icon came from.

Comment: We recommend you use `wsl.exe` instead of `bash.exe`. The former respects your configured default shell, etc. whereas the latter does not.

Comment: @RichTurner If I only have one shell (the default) will it matter? That said thanks for the advice and I will use `wsl.exe` going forward (after I reinstall over the broken 16.04).

Comment: bash.exe is deprecated and may be removed from future OS releases. Should be reason enough ;)

Comment: @RichTurner Well it gets rid of the awkward "Bash on Windows" too :)

Comment: @RichTurner when I try using e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -c ls` I get `/bin/bash: - : invalid option`. It seems `wsl.exe` doesn't grok `-c`?