# Ubuntu on Windows 10 Doesn't detect my Windows 10 Commands

Tags: bash, windows

I am currently trying to find the best way to use Bash on Windows 10 with Hyper, but at this point my last option was to ask here.

When I install these new "Ubuntu" applications for Windows 10, I want to have all my current Windows 10 features, just like Git for Windows.

For example, when I run `code .` to open Visual studio code(Installed on my windows 10), the bash from Git for Windows just open it, without installing it for that bash. Also is the same for Python, it detects my Windows's python.

The problem(MINGW64) is that its hard to do some stuff like changing the shell to Zsh or things like that. So I supose its better to have Ubuntu for Windows.

Now I have this problem, when I do `python --version` I get the message to install python... So I want to know how can I configure this Ubuntu to detect my Windows Path applications.

The point of my question is to not install again everything in this "ubuntu".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-installing programs to share them between Windows and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015285/cross-installing-programs)

Comment: @karel it doesnt have anything of that question.

Comment: Can you maybe run `python.exe` from Bash? Calling the Windows programms with their full file name should work, I think, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47663269/4464570

Comment: @SGarcia suggesting something is a duplicate is not 'unfriendly' or 'unkind', please don't use the 'unfriendly or unkind' flags for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is that it is kind of like a container.  While you're on Ubuntu via WSL, it will behave more like an isolated system (with your C: drive mounted) than a system where you can interact with the GUI.

Microsoft even says that it's not a replacement for the GUI.

git for Windows uses MINGW64, like you mentioned, and that operates more like Cygwin, which essentially is Linux commands that were compiled for Windows.  They behave more or less like Windows commands, which is why you can execute Windows commands within MINGW64.

In order to get Python to work within WSL, you will need to install it using apt like you would if it were a virtual machine or container.

Comment: Oh, then for me its useless since it will be more work to setup everything.
Anyways, thanks. Do you have any idea to make Zsh work on MINGW64?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Zsh but a quick google search [brought this up this gist](https://gist.github.com/aviaryan/5a57aa25b140f6c48f0e)