# How to get sound alert for any popup notifications (related to any application) in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, unity, sound, notification

I need to add a sound alert whenever the notification bar (notification related to any application) appears in Ubuntu 16.04, since I sometimes miss it because I am using a phone and not looking at the monitor. Just to be clear when I say notification bar I mean something and anything that looks like this:

[image: like this]

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: The image is just an example of poup notifications. All I need is to get a sound alert whenever theres a notification.

Comment: Sound is mentioned in documentation but I haven't tried it: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Sound

Comment: Something else you could do is automatically lock your screen after say two hours of use: [Application that will lock screen after a set amount of time for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu/837115#837115)